# Sending International Transfer from Jordan to Germany

Tags: money-transfer, international-transfer, germany, swift, iban

I am trying to send enrollment fee to a German account for my master's degree. The university provided me with details that included:

- Receiver name
- Bank name
- IBAN
- SWIFT/BIC

Do I need to use all these details when sending the transfer? My bank only asks for Receiver name + IBAN; can't add any other details when sending an international wire.

Would that be enough?